# Sharepoint - Announcement Permissions

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint

I've got a strange situation.  I've been added to a support role that has an older install of Sharepoint (2007).  One of my users approached me to ask me about a strange issue.  When she opens the main page and clicks into the "Add new Announcement" web part, the text boxes for Title and Expiration are available, but the body of the announcement is grayed out for her.

She's the only one that is affected by this as the admin accounts still have access.  Where do the permissions on that get set?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who saw this earlier and didn't answer, I have the answer.

It wasn't actually a sharepoint issue at all.  We discovered it's only in IE.  Chrome on any other PC renders the fields properly without graying them out.  Thank you for your time! :)

(and I should have caught that one earlier)

Comment: Specifically its the version of IE used.  IE8 should work fine.  9 may work. 10+ will have all kinds of strange problems with sharepoint.